# Select all negative value in a column

Tags: vba

I got the following code from this site, it selects all cells in column H containing the value "1" which works perfectly but I'm hoping that you can help me select all cells in column H containing negative values

```
Sub H()
    Dim TheSheet As Worksheet
    If TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        Set TheSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim CellsToSelect As String
    For Row = 1 To TheSheet.Range("H" & CStr(TheSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
        If TheSheet.Range("H" & CStr(Row)).Value = 1 Then
            If CellsToSelect <> "" Then CellsToSelect = CellsToSelect & ","
            CellsToSelect = CellsToSelect & "H" & CStr(Row)
        End If
    Next Row
    TheSheet.Range(CellsToSelect).Select
End Sub
```

Thank if advance
Noel

Comment: -1 because you want others to work for you for free.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line: `If TheSheet.Range("H" & CStr(Row)).Value = 1 Then`

To this: `If TheSheet.Range("H" & CStr(Row)).Value < 0 Then`

Here is the entire sub for your convenience.

```
 Sub H()
    Dim TheSheet As Worksheet
    If TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then
        Set TheSheet = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim CellsToSelect As String
    For Row = 1 To TheSheet.Range("H" & CStr(TheSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row
        If TheSheet.Range("H" & CStr(Row)).Value < 0 Then
            If CellsToSelect <> "" Then CellsToSelect = CellsToSelect & ","
            CellsToSelect = CellsToSelect & "H" & CStr(Row)
        End If
    Next Row
    If Len(CellsToSelect) <> 0 Then
        TheSheet.Range(CellsToSelect).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this before but I'm getting an error (Run-time error "104": Application defined or object-defined error)

Comment: Okay, the error you're referring to occurs if there are no cells in column H that meet the condition. I added an If statement just to make sure that there are some cells to select, so that it won't error if there aren't.

Comment: from row 1 to 66 this works fine but if I added another negitive value in row 67 onwards I get the error

Comment: Right. That's because `Range()` can only handle a string of approximately 255 characters. You'll need to refactor the formation of `CellsToSelect` to use colons for consecutive cells, but then you'll still run into problems if the amount of negative numbers and the amount to which they are spread out is excessive. You should ask yourself why you even want to do the selection. If you are trying to make them stand out, use conditional formatting. If you are trying to do something with them... they don't need to be selected.

Comment: I need to do this because I need to see the total of the negative values at the lower right corner of the sheet without having to modify it, I have alot of file to browse  quickly and have the estimate of their negative values. The total of the negative values dont exceed 100,000 btw